# json_encode behaving different on arrayObject vs array()

Tags: php, json, geojson

I had a function in php:

```
//simple method with array()
$sensors = array();
$query = "select id, x(transform(wkb_geometry,". $epsg . ")) as lon, y(transform(wkb_geometry,". $epsg . ")) as lat from mytable;";
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //var_dump($row);
    $mySensor = new sensor($row['id'],$row['lat'],$row['lon']);
    $sensors[] = $mySensor->geoJSON();
}

echo json_encode($sensors);
```

that outputs:

```
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 1579028,
    "x": 4.85310557823,
    "y": 52.7205622103,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [4.85310557823, 52.7205622103],
      "crs": {
        "type": "OGC",
        "properties": {
          "urn": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
      }
```

Now I have rewritten the array to become an object like this:

```
//advanced method with arrayObject:
class sensors extends ArrayObject {
    function __construct($epsg){
        $query = "select id, x(transform(wkb_geometry,". $epsg . ")) as lon, y(transform(wkb_geometry,". $epsg . ")) as lat from mytable;";
        $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
        while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //var_dump($row);
            $mySensor = new sensor($row['id'],$row['lat'],$row['lon']);
                $this[] = $mySensor->geoJSON();
            }
        }
    }
}
$newsensors = new sensors($epsg);
echo echo json_encode($newsensors);
```

But this changes the output to:

```
"features": {
  "0": {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 1579028,
    "x": 4.85310557823,
    "y": 52.7205622103,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [4.85310557823, 52.7205622103],
      "crs": {
        "type": "OGC",
        "properties": {
          "urn": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Which makes it unusable as geoJSON for OpenLayers. Why does the json_encode function behave this way? Can I turn off the setting of the index numbers? Is this a possible little bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`json_encode` will display the same behaviour with any object, even ones implementing the `ArrayAccess` interface as `ArrayObject` does; the public properties are used.

To get the behaviour that you want you should pass it an actual array which can be retrieved by calling `ArrayObject::getArrayCopy()` (or you can cast the object to an array).

```
echo json_encode($newsensors->getArrayCopy());
```

Answer (score 2):

Had to convert data trees that contain ArrayObject at different level so i wrote a piece of code to handle and convert every ArrayObject before outputting json, hope it helps :
https://github.com/nfroidure/Rest4/blob/master/php/class.Json.php

Comment: Nice solution, unfortunately I moved from php to node ;-) but maybe others may benefit

Answer (score 1):

Use the [JsonSerializable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) Interface (PHP 5 >= 5.4.0, PHP 7) and you should be safe:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return $this->getArrayCopy();
}
```